# regular expression unicode does not work in swift

Tags: swift, regex, unicode, emoji, nsregularexpression

```
let regex1 = "(\\ud83d\\udc68)"
let regex2 = "(\\ud83d[\\udc68-\\udc69])"

"".capturedGroupsFull(forRegex: regex1)
// returns 1 match: [(.0 "", .1 {0, 2})]
"".capturedGroupsFull(forRegex: regex2)
// returns nil
```

Why is the first line returning one match and the second line no match?

- Both regular expressions work fine on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hoZpRp/1) (e.g. set to
  javascript and use second regex as `(\ud83d[\udc68-\udc69])`).
- I am
  working with Swift 4.0.
- This regex `"(\\ud83d[\\udc68])"` will also
  return `nil` when testing in Playground.

Below you can find the full code I use to retrieve the matches.

```
extension String {
    func capturedGroupsFull(forRegex regex: String) -> [(String, NSRange)]? {
        let expression: NSRegularExpression
        do {
            expression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [.caseInsensitive])
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
        let nsString = self as NSString
        let matches = expression.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location:0, length: nsString.length))
        guard let match = matches.first else { return nil }
        var results = [(String, NSRange)]()
        for match in matches {
            let range = match.range
            let matchedString = nsString.substring(with: range)
            results.append((matchedString, range))
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

Comment: You can link regex101 btw.  Just click share regex

Comment: @chrisz thank you, updated the link. do you have any idea why it is not working with my code?

Comment: Which version of Swift?

Comment: @chrisz swift 4.0

Comment: The reason *could* be that NSRegularExpression operates on Unicode scalars and not on UTF-16 code units. With `regex2 = "([\\ud83d\\udc68-\\ud83d\\udc69])"` you'll get the expected result.

Comment: @MartinR indeed that works but it does not really solve my problem. Is there a way to make those javascript like regexes work in Swift? I want to avoid using `JSContext` and using the javascript regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Why is the first line returning one match and the second line no match?***

As already commented, `NSRegularExpression` works on Unicode code points and (normal) JavaScript regex works on UTF-16 code units.

Some patterns like `"\\ud83d\\udc68"`, which is made of a valid surrogate pair, may be optimized to a single Unicode code point U+1F468, but this feature is not well-documented, so you should not rely on it, as you found in the example `"(\\ud83d[\\udc68])"`.

---

I recommend not to use surrogate pair with `\uhhhh`, but use `\UHHHHHHHH` (or `\x{hhhh}`) for non-BMP characters.

```
let regex1 = "(\\U0001F468)" //or "(\\x{1F468})"
let regex2 = "([\\U0001F468-\\U0001F469])" // or "([\\x{1F468}-\\x{1F469}])"

"".capturedGroupsFull(forRegex: regex1)
// -> [(.0 "", .1 {0, 2})]
"".capturedGroupsFull(forRegex: regex2)
// -> [(.0 "", .1 {0, 2})]
```

Recent JavaScript regex accepts `u` option to make it work with Unicode code points, try these:

```
/(\u{1F468})/u
/([\u{1F468}-\u{1F469}])/u
```

You can easily test your regex pattern with JavaScript syntax and convert it to `NSRegularExpression` syntax with replacing `\u` to `\x` ( and removing `/` and `/u`).

Comment: Is there a way to make `NSRegularExpression` work on UTF-16 code units? I have a huge regex which requires work on UTF-16 code units and it is not feasible to rewrite that regex.

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi, no.